# Организация сочинения ЕГЭ

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос по организации работы. Возникла какая-то путаница.

Обязательно ли перед каждым примером формулировать аргумент? Просто в некоторых пособиях видела , что сразу после заявление собственной позиции идут примеры. И тезиса как такового тоже нет. То есть, например,так:

> Я согласна с автором. Действительно, жесткость среди подростков - это очень важный вопрос и, если мы не найдем верных путей его решения, итог может быть плачевным. Приведу примеры из литературы *(и дальше просто идут примеры проявления жестокости)* Так, примером послужит книга "Чучело"... *и т. д.* Повесть "Шут" также рассказывает о проявлении  детской жестокости... *и т. д.*

Правильно ли это? Просто как я понимаю, нужно сначала заявить четко тезис, а потом уже писать аргументы, которые будут ответом на этот тезис, и подбирать соответсвующие примеры. То есть здесь логичнее будет сказать, что, например, "жестокость - это ужасная проблема, которая требует решение" - тезис. Потом аргументы: во-первых, потому что ее проявление может привести к тяжелым последствиям, сказаться на психике детей и их душевном состоянии. И тогда уже пример с "Чучело".

Answer (score 1):

```
  Обязательно ли перед каждым примером формулировать аргумент?
```

Формулируют не аргумент, а тезис. Он как раз сформулирован:

```
 Действительно, жестокость среди подростков - это очень важный вопрос
   и, если мы не найдем верных путей его решения, итог может быть плачевным.
```

Аргумент-это пример, который доказывает Ваш тезис. Так что всё верно в приведённом Вами отрывке из сочинения. Много рассуждений не требуется, а вот сам пример проанализировать нужно, чтобы доказать правоту позиции автора и Вашей, а они должны совпадать.